# spring boot - load app config before calling method run

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

is there a way to read yaml file of a spring boot app before launching the app, more exactly before calling method run.

here is my code :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CometeRestApi extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

private static void setMongoSecure() {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.ssl/client-and-key.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "");

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.ssl/certificateChain.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustPassword", "");
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    setMongoSecure();
    return application.sources(CometeRestApi.class);
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    setMongoSecure();
    SpringApplication.run(CometeRestApi.class, args);
}
```

}

thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways to do it, but the recommended way is to use an EventListener. Annotating a method with `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` is ideal when your purpose is to automatically execute code after your application startup.

Comment: thanks for your reply but what i want is to read code before executing method run. i need to load some parameters from yaml config file(application.yml)  needed in function setMongoSecure()

Comment: you should place your initialization config in seperate properties file and load it and set it by calling System.setProperty(...).